# What's the difference between "Text" and "new Text" in dart?

Tags: dart

What's the difference between `Text` and `new Text` in dart?
Also suitable for Container and all other widgets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Dart 2, you don't need to use `new` keyword to create a new instance. So basically, if you're developing in Flutter and Dart 2+, `Text` and `new Text` is the same.

Take a look at the [Dart documentation about constructors](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#using-constructors).

Answer (score 2):

In Dart 2 `new` is an optional keyword. So `Text` and `new Text` is basically the same thing.